# Подскажите либу для этого виджета списка для Android

Tags: android, android-widgets

Всем привет! Хотелось бы в проекте добавить вот такой виджет[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не знаю точно как этот виджет называется, поэтому возникли затруднения во время поиска. Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/197

Comment: Виджет называется, как правило, Chip и реализаций [полно на github](https://github.com/search?utf8=✓&q=android+chip&type=)

Answer (score 5):

https://material.io/guidelines/components/chips.html

Компонент в Material называется chips, выбирайте подходящую реализацию:

https://github.com/search?utf8=&q=chips+android&type=